# faild my first web scraping using python going through python for everyone book

Tags: python, linux, ssl, web-scraping, urllib

i tried an example form book python for everyone where we are trying to scrape `https://docs.python.org` using **urllib** module but am not getting the supposed output and even book doesn't explains it all
here is the code

```
# search fo link values within URL input 
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

import re 

import ssl
# ignore ssl certificate errors

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input("Enter- ")

html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context = ctx).read()
links = re.findall(b'^href="(http[s]?://.*?)"',html)

for link in links:
    print(link.decode())
```

***output***

```
$ python3 urlregex.py
Enter- https://docs.python.org
```

and the supposed output was

```
Enter - https://docs.python.org
https://docs.python.org/3/index.html
https://www.python.org/
https://docs.python.org/3.8/
https://docs.python.org/3.7/
https://docs.python.org/3.5/
https://docs.python.org/2.7/
https://www.python.org/doc/versions/
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/
https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide
https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonBooks
https://www.python.org/doc/av/
https://www.python.org/
https://www.python.org/psf/donations/
http://sphinx.pocoo.org
```

Comment: Removing the ^ from the pattern should fix it so that line becomes `links = re.findall(b'href="(http[s]?://.*?)"',html)`   ... alternatively replace the ^ with a space which is a bit stricter and likely what the book text intended. ( ^ is a special character in regular expressions so it does seem to be inappropriate here)

Comment: thanks alot  i was bit confused with the code so i used it and it became long mess

Answer (score 0):

I  made mistake in regex part using ^ i removed it and it works smoothly